# Updating a tree and keeping track of the change in the nodes of some subtree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

**Problem:**
You are given a rooted tree where each node is numbered from 1 to N. Initially each node contains some positive value, say `X`. Now we are to perform two type of operations on the tree. Total `100000` operation.

**First Type:**

> Given a node **nd** and a positive integer **V**, you need to decrease the value of all the nodes by some amount. If a node is at a distance of **d** from the given node then decrease its value by **floor[v/(2^d)]**. Do this for all the nodes.
>   
> That means value of node **nd** will be decreased by **V** (i.e, floor[V/2^0]). Values of its nearest neighbours will be decreased by  **floor[V/2]** . And so on.

**Second Type:**

> You are given a node **nd**. You have to tell the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at **nd** whose value is positive.

**Note:** Number of nodes in the tree may be upto `100000` and the initial values, `X`, in the nodes may be upto `1000000000`. But the value of **V** by which the the decrement operation is to performed will be at most `100000`.

How can this be done efficiently? I am stuck with this problem for many days. Any help is appreciated.

My Idea : I am thinking to solve this problem offline. I will store all the queries first. then, if somehow I can find the time[After which operation] when some node **nd**'s value becomes less than or equal to zero(say it `death time`, for each and every node. Then we can do some kind of binary search (probably  using Binary Indexed Trees/ Segment Trees) to answer all the queries of second type. But the problem is I am unable to find the `death time` for each node.

Also I have tried to solve it online using **Heavy Light Decomposition** but I am unable to solve it using it either.

Thanks!

Comment: In the first type, do you decrease the values in the nearest neighbors' (whatever that means) nodes? Or do you decrease the node's children by `v/2^1` its grandchildren (child nodes' children) by `v/2^2`, etc.?

Comment: @JimMischel We not only decrease the value of node's children but also of its parent [that is what I meant by nearest neighbour, i.e, all those nodes which are at a distance of one unit from the given node] by V/2. Also this decrement is not only limited to its children and parent but the decrement is done to each and every node of the tree where the amount of decrement depends on the distance of the node from the given node.

Comment: Do you know all the operations beforehand, or do you need to do them one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Given a tree with vertex weights, there exists a vertex that, when chosen as the root, has subtrees whose weights are at most half of the total. This vertex is a "balanced separator".

Here's an O((n + k) polylog(n, k, D))-time algorithm, where n is the number of vertices and k is the number of operations and D is the maximum decrease. In the first phase, we compute the "death time" of each vertex. In the second, we count the live vertices.

To compute the death times, first split each decrease operation into O(log(D)) decrease operations whose arguments are powers of two between 1 and 2^floor(lg(D)) inclusive. Do the following recursively. Let v be a balanced separator, where the weight of a vertex is one plus the number of decrease operations on it. Compute distances from v, then determine, for each time and each power of two, the cumulative number of operations on v with that effective argument (i.e., if a vertex at distance 2 from v is decreased by 2^i, then record a -1 change in the 2^(i - 2) coefficient for v). Partition the operations and vertices by subtree. For each subtree, repeat this cumulative summary for operations originating in the subtree, but make the coefficients positive instead of negative. By putting the summary for a subtree together with v's summary, we determine the influence of decrease operations originating outside of the subtree. Finally, we recurse on each subtree.

Now, for each vertex w, we compute the death time using binary search. The decrease operations affecting w are given in a logarithmic number of summaries computed in the manner previously described, so the total cost for one vertex is log^2.

It sounds as though you, the question asker, know how the next part goes, but for the sake of completeness, I'll describe it. Do a preorder traversal to assign new labels to vertices and also compute for each vertex the interval of labels that comprises its subtree. Initialize a Fenwick tree mapping each vertex to one (live) or zero (dead), initially one. Put the death times and queries in a priority queue. To process a death, decrease the value of that vertex by one. To process a query, sum the values of vertices in the subtree interval.

Comment: I'm now aware that this is an active contest problem. With apologies to the CodeChef team, I'm leaving this answer up, so that everyone has the same access to it. Please don't waste your time vandalizing it.